# How to make a Trello session persist using Python as the client?

Tags: python, python-requests, trello

I'm trying to write a Python script that, from my command line, will allow me to:

1. Log in to Trello
2. Use the [Trello Python API](https://pythonhosted.org/trello/) to retrieve data from Trello boards, etc.

I'm restricted to using Python 2.7.6, so please don't offer any Python 3 suggestions — I won't be able to use them.

I'm able to log in to Trello using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module; however, I'm stuck on retrieving a user key in order to be able to use the Trello API.

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
import trello
import requests

# Not shown: retrieve username and password from user

sess = requests.Session()

loginData = {
    'method': 'password',
    'factors[user]': username,
    'factors[password]': password
}

TRELLO_LOGIN_URL = "https://trello.com/1/authentication"

resp = sess.post(TRELLO_LOGIN_URL, trelloLogin)     # resp => <Response [200]>
```

At this point, the `resp.text` consists of a dictionary (which works equally well in JavaScript or Python) containing a single key `code` whose value is a very long string of gibberish). I assume this (and the 200 status code in the response object) means that I logged in successfully.

So, now that I'm (presumably) logged in, I request the token URL from the API:

```
api = trello.TrelloApi(MY_API_KEY)
tokenUrl = api.get_token_url('MyApp') # => https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=<mykey>&name=MyApp&expiration=30days&response_type=token&scope=read,write
```

But when I try to use that URL:

```
sess.get(tokenUrl)
```

the response text I get (consisting of the HTML for an authorization page) has a "Log In" button, rather than the "Approve" button that I see when I do this in my browser. To me, this suggests that the `requests.Session` object is not persisting properly. Perhaps it's using incorrect cookies or something in the `get()` request?

Honestly, I'm not all that concerned about the nuts and bolts of what's going wrong, only about what I have to do to fix it. How do I make the session persist into that `get()` call so I can do the next part?

(Of course, it's entirely possible — even likely — that my approach is incorrect from the ground up, but I haven't been able to find any documentation to tell me what I should be doing differently, so this is the best I could come up with from what I *have* found. If there are instructions on doing this another way — but still from the command line — feel free to point me to them.)

Comment: Forgot to mention: 
`TRELLO_LOGIN_URL = https://trello.com/1/authentication` . Added to original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are 2 calls to make to get the token:

1. https://trello.com/1/authentication
   which contains the `code` string in the response
2. https://trello.com/1/authorization/session
   use the `code` retrieved previously to post, should return 204 and then `token` would be set to cookies. (You will also need to provide a `dsc` string, for the detail please try inspect the requests via the chrome dev tools.)

Comment: I see the authorization/session post with the `dsc` string, but I have no idea where to get that from.

Comment: @WilsonF The `dsc` field seems to be a server-generated string for csrf protection. Just make a request to `https://trello.com/login` first, then you should find it in the cookies.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at that, thanks. The project priority has been downgraded so it might be a while. In the meantime, this is probably the closest I'll get to a complete answer, so I'll accept it. : ) Thanks!